# I want to reuse a library of WPF UserControls - How can I set the styles?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, datatemplate

I have created a WPF desktop application using the MVVM pattern. As part of this effort, I have created a namespace with many dialog windows, dialogViewModels and dialogViews. The dialog windows typically display one of the dialogViews, depending on the assigned dialogViewModel.

I now want to convert the Views and ViewModels in this namespace to a separate library, so that I may reuse the dialogs in other applications. However, I have two questions:

1. How can I set the styles on my usercontrols so that, when the library is used in a different application, it uses the styles from that application.
2. Will I able to override datatemplate assignments made in the library controls when reusing the library?

Some code to illustrate my point:

```
<Window x:Class="FeehandlerMain.Dialogs.OKDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Path=DialogTitle}"
        Height="200" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" SizeToContent="Height">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dialogs:MessageBoxDialogViewModel}">
            <dialogs:MessageBoxDialogView /> 
        </DataTemplate>                           
    </Window.Resources>        

    <Border Style="{StaticResource StandardBorderStyle}" >
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"                   
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" IsCancel="True"
                        Style="{StaticResource StandardButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>           
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

**Question 1** is regarding the use of `StandardBorderStyle` and `StandardButtonStyle`. These styles are currently defined in my App.xaml file under `<Application.Resources>`. If I put the dialogs in a library, and I reference that library from a new application, how can I get the dialog to use `StandardBorderStyle` and `StandardButtonStyle` from the **new** application, so that each application can define it's own visual style?

**Question 2** is regarding the `DataTemplates`. These templates are used to select the appropriate view for the Dialog (inserted as a `ContentControl` element in the example above), based on the type of ViewModel assigned as the Dialog's DataContext. Will I be able to override the above DataTemplate when reusing the library, in a scenario where I want to use a different View than `MessageBoxDialogView` for `MessageBoxDialogViewModel`?

Oh and I know it's two questions, but you will still just get reputation for one answer, sorry! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the styles, the best way I can think of is to define a `DependencyProperty` for each of them in your own `UserControl`. So you'll have, for example, a `DependencyProperty` called `BorderStyle` which you set the default to the style you define internaly in your control library, while still allowing the client code using your control to override this style the way they want.

For the `DataTemplate`, you wouldn't really have to do anything, since the user of your library can define a another `DataTemplate` (for example for `MessageBoxDialogViewModel`) in his code, and that would take precedence and be used instead of the default one.

Hope this helps :)